# FireBase Rest with auth query param not working

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
   // INIT FIREBASE
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
          .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("C:\\path\\testcustom-dff2147d3b14.json"))
          .setDatabaseUrl("https://testcustom-a1a4d.firebaseio.com/")
          .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        isFireBaseInit = true;

       // GENERATE TOKEN
        String uid = "USER ID SOME RANDOM";
        HashMap<String, Object> additionalClaims = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        String token = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims);
```

Not from browser if i try to use rest api to fetch data

[https://testcustom-a1a4d.firebaseio.com/1719126/1719130/1719121.json?auth=TOKEN GENERATOR IN JAVA CODE](https://testcustom-a1a4d.firebaseio.com/1719126/1719130/1719121.json?auth=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2lkZW50aXR5dG9vbGtpdC5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9nb29nbGUuaWRlbnRpdHkuaWRlbnRpdHl0b29sa2l0LnYxLklkZW50aXR5VG9vbGtpdCIsImNsYWltcyI6eyJ0aW1lQm94SWQiOiIxNzE5MTIxIiwidGVzdFJlc3VsdElkIjoiMTcxOTEzMCIsInRlc3RJZCI6IjE3MTkxMjYiLCJkZWJ1ZyI6dHJ1ZX0sImV4cCI6MTQ3MjAyNjg1MywiaWF0IjoxNDcyMDIzMjUzLCJpc3MiOiJmaXJlYmFzZUB0ZXN0Y3VzdG9tLWExYTRkLmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiZmlyZWJhc2VAdGVzdGN1c3RvbS1hMWE0ZC5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSIsInVpZCI6IjE3MTkxMjYxNzE5MTMwMTcxOTEyMSJ9.ed1_ooA0FEDZ5vn5_JKROfS2ovT9RDjbu22LIYrKgqsMUbOtQ5J73N4--RsILfIUoc10_I4Iv5UBUezTRIVmJ6LusY5oGz9a37ehQcd8-mBdamiySSBdgdw_AB5g4o_1-WoRaTr3FLCKyPLl0xnfwboUTZOK_TIAxwh9ujvelR7ymq4xhA6rp2Ghf6pU30xraCO3UVNeYD9fzox1zcg9HB3_z3ew4MWFt8mpwXSdzZnE3yZAMohvlRUH6--oXsE9a8upCEEK0a7yzqw7HSFE-GGt1O5l5nK-Y0tUC5pVc6gEFIK8sH06RO8zwiYTREywUv9a9JBuRZheLTsaHHIhew)

I get following error:

```
{
  "error" : "Missing claim 'kid' in auth header."
}
```

**What am i doing wrong?**

Does custom token doesnot work with rest api.
DO i need to use [firebase link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth), If yes how to add additional claim in it ?

PS:
firebase sdk version i am using

com.google.firebase
    firebase-server-sdk
    3.0.1

**EDIT: THERE IS A INCONSISTENCY IN FIREBASE DOCUMENTATION**

---

FIREBASE [GUIDE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#auth) DOCUMENTATION SAYS

> The argument can either be your Firebase app's secret or an
>   authentication token, as described in the "Users in Firebase Projects"

Type of authentication described are https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#auth_tokens
*Note: custom token is present there*

---

FIREBASE [REFERENCE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-param-auth) DOCUMENTATION SAYS

> The argument can either be your Firebase app's secret or an
>   authentication token. See the [REST authentication documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth)
>   for details.

---

So Guide and reference talk differently.

**Need help please**

Answer (score 2):

From firebase support team

> Yes, creating custom tokens using
>   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims)
>   does not work with REST API. These tokens are designed to be used by
>   client SDKs with signInWithCustomToken(token). Please note that
>   "client to DB" REST requests are not supported right now due to
>   changes in security model in the new Firebase (legacy Firebase
>   supports it).
>
> As you have pointed out, you need to follow this link in order to make
>   an authenticated REST request. You should to use the access_token
>   parameter, passing the token derived from the service account private
>   key. This assumes you're scenario is "Server to DB" as you're using a
>   service account.
>
> To add custom claims using REST, you should use the
>   auth_variable_override parameter. See here. Your request should now
>   look like this with the added claim:
>   {"uid":"6LiF16Dm0hNB9XO61UR1KM5Jeun2"}
>
> $ curl
>   "https://test-de98f.firebaseio.com/test.json?access_token=&auth_variable_override=%7B%22uid%22%3A%226LiF16Dm0hNB9XO61UR1KM5Jeun2%22%7D"
>   {" 1213314":{"alanisawesome":"Alan Turing"}}
>
> I do understand that the documentation you have pointed out needs to
>   be improved and have raised this to our documentation team so that it
>   could be prioritized appropriately. Though, I can't share any
>   timelines as of the moment.
>
> Hope this helps. Feel free to respond for any more issues or concerns.